# В какой виджет выводятся текст, картинки, видео?

Tags: c++, c, qt, gtk

Например в мессенджерах можно писать текст, вставлять картинки, вставлять может быть видео. Но в какой виджет это всё вставляется я не пойму? Для примера можно и qt и gtk. Откуда программисты узнали что в этот виджет можно вставлять разные данные помимо текста?

Comment: что-то я подумал что можно наверное в web виджет какой нибудь выводить, который со стилями всякими будет оформление задавать. Но так ли это?

Comment: Как вариант - можно использовать QML вместо виджетов.

Comment: _«Откуда программисты узнали»_ из документации. Виджеты для разных типов сообщений могут использоваться разные, а можно сделать и  самописный виджет, в котором уже обрабатывать разные ситуации.

Comment: в QLabel можно вставить практически все.

Comment: я думал что нужно использовать виджет webview, в котором код на javascript  для обработки текста рисунков и видео и css для вида. Но оказалось что javascript не может в mysql запросы отправлять и нужно что-то другое.